# Powershell script works but not in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I need to run a powershell script from vb.net. I wrote it and tried it in powershell ISE and the powershell console and it's working properly.

But when I try to use it in my vb.net code, nothing happens.

The script put into text file citrix session from some user.

here is my powershell script :

```
$username = 'domain\myusername'
$password = 'mypassword'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Credential $credential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "add-pssnapin citrix*`nGet-BrokerSession -AdminAddress 'ipadresshere' | Out-File -FilePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gestusers\ajax\data\arrays.txt"
```

and here's my vb.net code :

```
Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

        ' open it
        MyRunSpace.Open()

        ' create a pipeline and feed it the script text
        Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

        MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)

        ' add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
        ' remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script
        ' "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.
        MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")

        ' execute the script
        Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

        ' close the runspace
        MyRunSpace.Close()

        ' convert the script result into a single string
        Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        For Each obj As PSObject In results
            MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
        Next

        ' return the results of the script that has
        ' now been converted to text
        Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()
```

When I try to use a smaller script like :

```
$test = "blablabla"
$test | Out-File -filepath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gestusers\ajax\data\arrays.txt"
```

it works so I don't really understand why the first script is not working .. if you have some suggestion I would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found a solution to my problem.
I am running my web app on a IIS server and when I was launching my script it was the default user "IIS default/application_pool" which was lauching it although I specified a specific user to run it, it was like my script doesn't work.

So I choosed to go in my IIS server params and I just made an other app_pool with my specific user. I put my app under this pool and now it works perfectly.

Here's how to make a specific pool on IIS Server : https://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511/IIS-and-ASPNET-The-Application-Pool.htm

cya